# What is the good batch size and optimizer for large datasets?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a dataset of 45000 images.

1)How much batch size should i use for large datasets like this.?

2)And what optimiser should I use like Adam or SGD ,I have bit confusion always to choose optimiser.

Environment: I7-8750h and GTX 1060(6GB)

Comment: You can try to compare using various parameters, and see which configuration is the best for you

Answer (score 3):

45K is not a large dataset, this is smaller than the MNIST dataset (60K images).

But anyways, nobody can make batch size and optimizer recommendations, its something you have to tune in your own dataset and model. You can start with Adam and see if the model converges, if not go back to SGD.